# SSL certificate validation using Java client

Tags: java, ssl, okhttp

I am writing a micro service which talks to another service through HTTPS. In java client implementation, reading root certificate from truststore and then validate incoming certificate through that.

Now, my question is - by default only 2nd level certificate will be validated using root Cert or all chained certificates in turn will also get validated?

I am Using okhttp; and my assumption is that all Java clients should behave in same way, please let me know if there is any subjectivity here? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you include the root certificate in the truststore, the entire chain will be validated

The SSL server during handshake sends to client the certification chain from leaf certificate to root. The root certificate may be included but usually it is not

The default Trust Manager of a Java client will validate the provided certification chain looking in the truststore until it find the issuer of the certificate or the certificate itself

Comment: Let's take this case: Certificate chain is root -> cert1 -> cert2 -> cert3. When handshake starts, server is going to send cert1 -> cert2 -> cert3. So, will client only validate cert1 using root and then implicitly reach conclusion that all chain is valid or does it validate cert2 and cert3 as well ?

Comment: The chain is sent and verified in reverse cert3 -> cert2 -> cert1 -> root. Client will validate cert3, cert2, and cert1 until the root  is found

Comment: So signature cert3 will be verified using cert2 which is any way coming from server. So what value it will deliver ? Also, does Java implementation validate owner domain, dates and other such details ? And, all java http clients behave in similar fashion ?

Comment: A SSL client (not only Java) must verify that the issuer of cert3 is cert2, cert2 is issued by cert1 and cert1 is issued by root. This is done verifying the digital signature (a certificate is signed with its issuer). The domain is also verified checking that the domain name match with the CN attribute of the leaf certificate (cert3). Validity dates are also verified. This behaviour can be changed using a custom TrustManager or HostNameVerifier